# Can't create Facebook test accounts anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate the Go Live feature in our desktop application to create a stream, but the tests are very painfull. After creating a few test accounts, with the "Test" role for the facebook app, they are all blocked for now.

Just, why FB?! I had a dev account, create a FB app, and set the "Test" role to the test account, but after 2 success streaming broadcasts the account was blocked. Now I can't create FB account anymore because my phone number is blacklist due to the number of accounts linked to it.

How can I solve it? It's really, really annoying.

Comment: You did use your own, personal profile that bears your real name for your app development, as you are required to, right …?

Comment: Hum no, I don't want to use my personal account to test some streaming and more ... Is it mandatory?

Comment: That’s not about testing, but about who is the app admin/developer. If you use fake accounts to admin your app, then don’t complain if stuff gets blocked or remove. Testing using test users is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help I have solved this issue. Please write an answer then I will close this post.